# Unable to change image src with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I know this has been asked; and I've read most of the asked questions to no avail. I still am having trouble. I want to click an image and have the image source change (thus having the image change).

This is my HTML:

```
 <img id="picture1" onclick="showHide('builder1'); change('picture1');" width="25" height="25" src="pictures/down.png">
```

Ignore the "showHide('builder1');". It's working. I need help on the change('picture1').

And this is my Javascript:

```
function change(id)
{
   var isDown = true;
   var picture = document.getElementById(id);
   if(isDown === true)
   {
      picture.src = "pictures/pullup.png";
      isDown = false; //No longer a down arrow...
   }
   else
   {
      picture.src = "pictures/down.png";
      isDown = true;
   }
}
```

I am able to change the picture once (to 'pictures/pullup.png') but can't change it back.
I also added alerts at certain points in the if/else statement to see where it was at; and it never even reached the 'else' part of the statement.

Comment: `isDown` is always going to be `true` so you'll never get the `else` statement.

Comment: declare `isDown` outside the function (if possible make sure it should not be global).

Comment: You're setting isDown to true on every click.

Comment: @MightyPork I assure you, it's *that* bad.

Comment: I agree with @MightyPork. The mistake is silly unless the OP got the idea that variables in JS were static, but the question is complete with a demonstration of what was attempted and a clear description of the expected vs observed output. He even described the debugging efforts. The DVs seem just a little heavy on this one. In terms of quality of the post, this is one of the better questions.

Comment: For y'all: upvotes are ***not*** suited for taking away others' right to downvote...

Comment: @user3477950: Upvotes are for rating the quality of the question, and this question is better than most on this site. As the upvote title states *"this question shows research effort; it is useful and clear"*. It meets all the qualifications.

Comment: ...and no one is taking away your "rights". You still have the right to vote. However I'd have a hard time believing that the downvote title could be convincingly applied to this question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Move `var isDown = true;` outside the function scope - define it before the function.

This way, every time you run the function, you set the variable to `true` first.

---

Based on Mike's comment: you could also use something like this:

```
picture.src = "pictures/"
               + (picture.src=="pictures/pullup.png" ?
                                                     "pulldown.png"
                                                     : "pullup.png");
```

Or with an IF if you dislike ternary.

Comment: You can also get rid of `isDown` completely, and just base the logic off the current `picture.src`

Comment: This will work as long as there's only one `img` using that variable. If there are more, he could put a boolean property directly on the element by passing it in. That way each element maintains its own state.

Answer (score 0):

You are defining `isDown` in the same statement, everytime, to be true. So it will never reach the `else` block of your conditional statement.

Comment: You don't need jQuery to do a `keydown` event. And I don't see how a keydown event would be useful here.

Comment: I'd remove the second paragraph.  It has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, removed the second paragraph.